# Use decorated methods (@property) in datatable's fields array (django-eztables)

Tags: python, django, datatables

I'm using `django-eztables` app (0.3.2), and I'm trying to use some model's properties within fields:

**model's class:**

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def a_property(self):
        return 'something'
```

**eztables' view:**

```
class AView(DatatablesView):
    model = AModel
    fields = [
        ...,
        "a_property",
    ]
```

According to what I saw, this cannot work because method `process_dt_response` in eztables' `DatatablesView` class uses `.values(*self.get_db_fields())` on the queryset.

The only way to do this is that I found is to overwrite mentioned method within my `AView` class, and just remove mentioned `values` call:

```
def process_dt_response(self, data):
    self.form = DatatablesForm(data)
    print self.form
    if self.form.is_valid():
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        return self.render_to_response(self.form)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Is this ok (will it have some other bad side-effects)? Is there any other, better way to do this?

Comment: And even my proposed solution doesn't work - when there is some data to return, `get_rows` method is raising an exception on columns which are not real in database (mentioned methods' properties).

Answer (score 0):

One strategy that worked for me was to append additional data just before it was returned to the client. render_to_response() calls get_row() to get the final array (for each record). Override get_row() and append custom data. One assumption here though is that all the data required to get/generate the additional custom data is available in get_row().